# How can I set a button background image on iPhone under Monotouch?

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, uibutton, xamarin.ios

How can I set a button background image on iPhone under Monotouch?
It will be better if you provide me same sample.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will set a background image on a button:

```
button.SetBackgroundImage (UIImage.FromBundle ("imageFile"), UIControlState.Normal);
```

You can set different images for different control states with the UIControlState parameter.

Comment: Where can I put image in project, please advice?

Comment: You can put it in any location or folder, as long as it is *not* called "Resources" as this is a reserved folder name. You will need to make sure your image's build action is set to "Content" too.